# Database connection error; cached?

Tags: database, ce-1.9.0.1

I accidentally overwrote `/app/etc/local.xml` with a version from another host. No live shop affected, luckily, but I can't get the shop to connect to the database anymore. It keeps saying:

There has been an error processing your request

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'wronguser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I've restored the correct local.xml, with the correct database settings. I cleared var/cache and var/sessions.

When running `n98-magerun db:console` I can access the database, but it's impossible to run `n98-magerun cache:clean` or any other database related command.

Removing any other .xml files from /app/etc/ didn't resolve the issue either.
`grep -R wronguser *` didn't even find the wrong database connection in the entire document root. I have no idea where Magento gets this information from.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try removing your entire /var/cache folder?

Comment: Yes I did. After reloading the page, the directory is created again, but left empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If cache folder stays empty - it might be that Redis cache backend is used.
Then you'll have to connect to Redis CLI and flush caches there to make Magento re-read settings from local.xml.

Comment: I really should've thought of that! You're a life saver:)

`redis-cli -n 0 flushdb` 
did the trick!

Comment: Glad to help :)